# Page footer not showing in pdfmake

Tags: jquery, datatables, pdfmake

I have the following code which generates a datatable pdf upon pdf click. Inside the customize function, I have a footer code which is supposed to display page numbers.

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
            //SHOW EXSITING LINE ITEMS
            var id = @Model.Order.Id;
            table = $("#orders").DataTable({
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                 {
                    text: 'Download PDF',
                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                    className:'btn btn-primary',
                    orientation: 'landscape',                   
                    },
                    customize: function (doc) {               
                        //set header
                        doc.content[0].text = "SALES ORDER";
                        doc.page
                        doc.pageMargins = [10, 10, 10, 10];
                        doc.defaultStyle.fontSize = 12;
                        doc.styles.tableHeader.fontSize = 14;
                        doc.styles.title.fontSize = 14;
                        // Set page title
                        doc.content[0].text = "SALES ORDER";
                        // Create a footer
                        doc.footer = (function (page, pages) {
                            return {
                                columns: [
                                    'This is your left footer column',
                                    {
                                        // This is the right column
                                        alignment: 'center',
                                        text: ['page ', { text: page.toString() }, ' of ', { text: pages.toString() }]
                                    }
                                ],
                                margin: [10, 0]
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            ],
```

I have added a footer code as seen above but I cannot seem to get the footer in my pdf. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

Basically you have not left space for the footer. You can use `doc.pageMargins` to increase the available space at the bottom of the page, for example

```
doc.pageMargins = [10, 10, 45, 20]
```

You must take care of margins and size in the footer as well. A footer with some text to the left and page numbers to the right could look like this:

```
doc.footer = function(page, pages) {
  return {
    margin: [5, 0, 10, 0],
    height: 30,
    columns: [{
      alignment: "left",
      text: 'This is your left footer column',
    }, {
      alignment: "right",
      text: [
        { text: page.toString(), italics: true },
          " of ",
        { text: pages.toString(), italics: true }
      ]
    }]
  }
}
```

demo -> **https://jsfiddle.net/np8em3sx/**

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the page margins
[pdfmake github issue](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/739#issuecomment-258511202)